# The file format and the extension do not match in Excel downloaded from an API

Tags: c#, excel, httpclient

I am downloading an Excel from an API. The download works fine but when i try to open the excel file, the error "The file format and the extension do not match" is getting displayed.

Anything else needed in code? When i manually hit the url, the excel file is downloaded is i am able to open the file.

The file type when downloaded manually is .xls format, so am setting the format as .xls in the code

Code

```
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {

                    //HTTPClient to download the report

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "XXXX");

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                    var response = client.GetAsync(url);

                    if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (Stream streamToReadFrom = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                        {
                            //Saving the report to a local path
                            using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(localpath, FileMode.Create))
                            {
                                streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo).Wait();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Things like this usually happen when the file is saved in the new format (XLSX extension) but the file itself is the old format (XLS extension).

Comment: Yeah that also caused the issue intially, the file format was xls and i was trying to save it as xlsx. I changed it to XLS and it worked fine after correcting the url.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the report download URL was incorrect. My bad, correct URL fixed the issue.